# CSS stylesheet not being applied

Tags: css

Since about a week I have a problem getting my CSS stylesheet loaded. I have the following code:

Version 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    <?PHP include_once "school.css"; ?>
    </style>
</head>
```

Version 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="school.css" />
</head>
```

I tested the stylesheet with online validation pages and there where no error messages. I use the following browsers: Chrome and Firefox on the following devices: Windows XP, Windows 7, Nexus 7. All of them show the same problem:

I load the page and the stylesheet seems to have been loaded, but it is not applied. When I navigate through the page, the stylesheet is still not applied. The same stylesheet should be applied, but isn't. When I refresh, or force refresh the page, the stylesheet is being applied and everything is OK from that point on. Even if I change the stylesheet and then refresh the page the changes will be shown without any problem. ONLY ON THE FIRST LOAD THERE IS A PROBLEM.

I have many similar pages with stylesheets and they still work. Here is the stylesheet:

```
/***********
* MY STYLE *
***********/


/* GENERAL */

    html, body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        font-family: "MS Gothic";
    }

/* COLORS */

    body {
        color: black;
    }
    #banner a, h2, #tabbar a, th, input[type="submit"] {
        color: #ffe6cc;
        text-shadow:
         0.05em  0.05em  0.05em #2f2200,
         0.05em  0       0.05em #2f2200,
         0.05em -0.05em  0.05em #2f2200,
         0       0.05em  0.05em #2f2200,
         0      -0.05em  0.05em #2f2200,
        -0.05em  0.05em  0.05em #2f2200,
        -0.05em  0       0.05em #2f2200,
        -0.05em -0.05em  0.05em #2f2200;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #ffe6cc;
    }
    #banner, h2, #tabbar a {
        background-color: #665533;
    }
    th, input[type="submit"] {
        background-color: #887755;
    }

/* BORDERS */

    .tablePrices tr:first-child > *, .tabbar, #imgTeacher, #aMap img, input[type="text"], input[type="submit"], input[type="tel"], input[type="email"], select, textarea {
        border-top: 0.15em solid #2f2200;
    }
    .tablePrices tr:first-child > *:first-child, .tablePrices tr > *:first-child, #imgTeacher, #aMap img, input[type="text"], input[type="submit"], input[type="tel"], input[type="email"], select, textarea {
        border-left: 0.15em solid #2f2200;
    }
    .tablePrices tr > *, .tabbar a, #imgTeacher, #aMap img, input[type="text"], input[type="submit"], input[type="tel"], input[type="email"], select, textarea {
        border-right: 0.15em solid #2f2200;
    }
    h1, h2, #navMenu h2:last-child:last-child > div, h3, .tablePrices tr > *, #imgTeacher, #aMap img, input[type="text"], input[type="submit"], input[type="tel"], input[type="email"], select, textarea {
        border-bottom: 0.15em solid #2f2200;
    }

/* BANNER */

    #banner {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    .banner h1 {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
    .banner a {
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 0.5em 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    h2 {
        margin: 0;
    }
    h2 span {
        display: block;
    }

/* TABBAR */

    #tabbar {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    #tabbarDummy {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .tabbar a {
        display: inline-block;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 20%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .tabbar a:last-child {
        border-right: 0;
    }

/* ARTICLE */

    article {
        padding: 1em 1em 0 1em;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    article > *:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }

    p {
        margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
    }

/* COURSES */

    .tablePrices {
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 0;
        width: 50%;
        min-width: 15em;
        margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
    }
    .tablePrices th {
        padding: 0.2em;
    }
    .tablePrices td {
        padding: 0.2em;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .tablePrices tr:first-child > *:first-child {
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0.5em;
        -moz-border-topleft-radius: 0.5em;
        border-top-left-radius: 0.5em;
    }
    .tablePrices tr:first-child > *:last-child {
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0.5em;
        -moz-border-topright-radius: 0.5em;
        border-top-right-radius: 0.5em;
    }
    .tablePrices tr:last-child > *:first-child {
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5em;
        -moz-border-bottomleft-radius: 0.5em;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5em;
    }
    .tablePrices tr:last-child > *:last-child {
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5em;
        -moz-border-bottomright-radius: 0.5em;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5em;
    }

/* TEACHER */

    #imgTeacher {
        float: right;
        margin: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
        max-width: 50%;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0.5em;
        -moz-border-radius: 0.5em;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    #pTeacher {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
    #divTeacher {
        clear: both;
        margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    }

/* MAP */

    #aMap {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #aMap img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0.5em;
        -moz-border-radius: 0.5em;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    #divMap {
        text-align: center;
    }
    #divMap p {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
        text-align: left;
    }

/* INQUIRY */

    #tableInquiry {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto 1em auto;
    }
    #tableInquiry .tdLabel {
        width: 1%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        padding: 0.1em;
        text-align: right;
    }
    #tableInquiry .tdLabelLong {
        padding: 0.1em;
        text-align: left;
    }
    #tableInquiry .tdRed {
        color: red;
    }
    #tableInquiry .tdField {
        width: 99%;
        padding: 0.1em;
    }
    #tableInquiry .tdTrial {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #tableInquiry .tdSpacer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 0.5em;
    }
    #tableInquiry .spanNoWrap {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    #tableInquiry .tdButton {
        padding: 0.1em;
        text-align: right;
    }
    #pInquirySuccess {
        color: #009900;
        text-align: center;
    }

/* INQUIRY: INPUT FIELDS */

    input[type="text"], input[type="tel"], input[type="email"], select, textarea {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0.1em;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0.3em;
        -moz-border-radius: 0.3em;
        border-radius: 0.3em;
    }
    textarea {
        height: 12em;
        resize: vertical;
    }
    input[type="submit"] {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0.3em;
        -moz-border-radius: 0.3em;
        border-radius: 0.3em;
    }

/* BANNER IMAGE */

@media only screen and (max-width: 319px) {
    #banner h1 {
    background-image: url("/images/school/banner_small.jpg");
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 759px) {
    #banner h1 {
    background-image: url("/images/school/banner_medium.jpg");
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 760px) {
    #banner h1 {
    background-image: url("/images/school/banner.jpg");
    }
}

/* PORTRAIT: FONT SIZE */

@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) and (max-width: 279px) {
    * { font-size: 12px; }
}
@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) and (min-width: 280px) and (max-width: 319px) {
    * { font-size: 14px; }
}
@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 399px) {
    * { font-size: 16px; }
}
@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 479px) {
    * { font-size: 20px; }
}
@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) and (min-width: 480px) {
    * { font-size: 24px; }
}

/* LANDSCAPE: FONT SIZE */

@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 419px) {
    * { font-size: 12px; }
}
@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) and (min-width: 420px) and (max-width: 479px) {
    * { font-size: 14px; }
}
@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 599px) {
    * { font-size: 16px; }
}
@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 719px) {
    * { font-size: 20px; }
}
@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) and (min-width: 720px) {
    * { font-size: 24px; }
}

/* PORTRAIT */

@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {

    .banner a {
        font-size: 200%;
    }

    h2 {
        padding: 1em 1em;
    }
    h2 span {
        font-size: 150%;
    }

    .tabbar img {
        display: block;
        width: 2em;
        margin: 0.5em auto;
    }
    .tabbar span {
        font-size: 75%;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0 0 0.666em 0;
    }

}

/* LANDSCAPE */

@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {

    .banner a {
        font-size: 150%;
    }

    h2 {
        padding: 0.5em 1em;
    }
    h2 span {
        font-size: 125%;
    }

    .tabbar img {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 2em;
        margin: 0.25em 0.5em 0.25em 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .tabbar span {
        font-size: 75%;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Bernhard

Comment: is the css file in the same folder as your page?

Comment: Which one are you using? Version 1 or Version 2? What is the folder structure of your html file and css file?

Comment: Mladen Oršolić Yes, of course. On refreshing the page, it is applied correctly.

Comment: mwan Folder structure? It's in "www/design/school_3/". How I said, the stylesheet is working perfectly after refreshing the page.

Comment: I tried both versions. Both the same problem.

Comment: Refresh after commenting out the ruleset: `#banner a, h2, #tabbar a, th, input[type="submit"] {
        color: #ffe6cc;
        text-shadow:
         0.05em  0.05em  0.05em #2f2200,
         0.05em  0       0.05em #2f2200,
         0.05em -0.05em  0.05em #2f2200,
         0       0.05em  0.05em #2f2200,
         0      -0.05em  0.05em #2f2200,
        -0.05em  0.05em  0.05em #2f2200,
        -0.05em  0       0.05em #2f2200,
        -0.05em -0.05em  0.05em #2f2200;
    }`

Comment: zer00ne: It didn't help. Still the same problem. Maybe too many @media rules? But I removed them and no change.

Comment: I removed the whole stylesheet and just put a dummy style like background: brown for the body tag. The same thing. Nothing happens, and after reload everything OK !!!

Comment: What services are you using? S3? Word-Press? a CMS? Using any proxies?

Comment: I'm just using a php server. I saw some posts about using the right encoding and I tried utf-8 without BOM and it didn't work. Then I tried other stuff, and now it is working again! A little hick-up? Anyways thanks for all the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
Version 1 :

    <?php
    function my_theme_enqueue_styles()
    {
    $parent_style = 'adforest-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/school.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/school.css', array( $parent_style ), wp_get_theme() >get('1.0.0') );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
    ?>

    @import url("../css/school.css");




    Version 2 :

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/school.css" />
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```